# Dropdown lists OnSelected Index changed event and Gridview Respond to two dropdown lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have got 2 DropDownLists on my Form and 1 GridView. I want the GridView to display the data according to the selection from the DropDownLists.

For Example, One DropDownList contains GroupNames and another contains Status. Both the DropDownLists can post back. So if I select a groupname from 1st DropDownList, the GridView should show all the results according to that Name. Similarly if i select the status from the other DropDownList , the GridView should show the results according to the status. But i cant figure out as how to bind GridView to respond to 2 DropDownLists.

BTW i am binding the 1st Drop Down Lists and the Grid View to the DataSource Objects, which is getting data from the database. and i am getting error if i am binding the same datasource to second dropdown how to bind second dropdown to same gridview.

Any Suggestions??
please help??

Comment: did you tried the selected changed event?

Comment: Yes I am new to coding i am not getting how to get the data from ddlselectindex from two dropdowns .. please help

Comment: post the code what you tried, so that it will be easy where it got stuck , that's how SO works

Comment: I gave you sample image by seeing that please guide me to develop code

Comment: Put your code inside your `Main Post` not in a comment.

Comment: @jones that's the O/P , i'm asking about code.. post this code in question , so tat viewing can be done easily

Comment: I am not able to edit that it shows some kind of errros ..

Comment: Click on Edit on your post and paste your code there under the description of problem.

Comment: I havent tried any coding because i dono how to get the data in gridview on selected index changed

Comment: can you show how  are you binding the data with grid

Answer (score 0):

Set your `dropdownLists` `AutoPostBack="true"`, populate lists within `page_load` by checking if it's not a `postBack` and then your event of `SelectedIndexChange` will fire.

.aspx Code:

```
       <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlGroupName" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGroupName_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" />
        <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="gv1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Id" DataField="Id" />
                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Group Name" DataField="GroupName" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>
```

Classes to populate your `DropDownLists`:

```
    public class Groups
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
    }
    public class transMedHandler
    {
        public static List<Groups> GetGroupNames()
        {
            return new List<Groups>() 
            {
                new Groups {Id = 1, GroupName = "cardia connections" }, 
                new Groups { Id = 2, GroupName = "citizens group" }, 
                new Groups { Id = 3, GroupName = "testgroup etc" }
            };
        }
        public static List<Groups> GetNames()
        {
            return new List<Groups>() 
            { 
                new Groups { Id = 1, GroupName = "active" }, 
                new Groups { Id = 2, GroupName = "assigned" }, 
                new Groups { Id = 3, GroupName = "returned" }, 
                new Groups{ Id = 4, GroupName = "deactivated" }
            };
        }
    }
```

I've used classes so that you can populate these lists by some table in your db as well.
And finally Back-end code for event handling and manipulation stuff.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //populating ddlGroupName DropDown
            ddlGroupName.DataSource = transMedHandler.GetGroupNames();
            ddlGroupName.DataTextField = "GroupName";
            ddlGroupName.DataValueField = "Id";
            ddlGroupName.DataBind();
            ddlGroupName.SelectedIndex = 0;
            //populating ddlStatus DropDown
            ddlStatus.DataSource = transMedHandler.GetNames();
            ddlStatus.DataTextField = "GroupName";
            ddlStatus.DataValueField = "Id";
            ddlStatus.DataBind();
            ddlStatus.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    protected void GetGroupNames() 
    {
        gv1.DataSource = transMedHandler.GetGroupNames();
        gv1.DataBind(); 
    }
    protected void GetNames()
    {
        gv1.DataSource = transMedHandler.GetNames();
        gv1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void ddlGroupName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetGroupNames(); 
    }
    protected void ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetNames();
    }
```

You can make changes in the `gridView`, DropDown manipulation classes etc according to your need. I've written/tested this code, it works perfectly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: well in coming days group names may increase, and in drop downs list items may increase there may be problem at dat time writng items again in the list manually ..

Comment: That's why you don't need that class to get items, just get data from db and set them to `dropdownlist` and the rest of the code will remain unchanged. It solved your problem or not?

Comment: whats the issue now? My solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: No its not working, i have changed the code but the gridview should respond to two dropdowns its not working.. please if possible help me with the total code..

Comment: and the issue is we cant set the same datasource to drop downs.. how to create multiple data sources

Comment: You can create as many datasources as you want. Create a method which will return you some different datasource with same properties, the above code will work in that scenario too. But if you want to change GridView Column name and properties then you have to do the same work for items having different properties.